# Has anyone successfully integrated qtranslate with custom metaboxes?

Tags: metabox, plugin-qtranslate

I followed [this](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/04/how-to-create-meta-box-wordpress-post.html) tutorial to create custom metaboxes.

It seems like [qtranslate](http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/) enables you to use shortcodes almost everywhere.
For example:

Post titles:

```
<!--:en-->Cheng Feng Enterprises<!--:--><!--:zh-->鄭峰企業<!--:--><!--:es-->Cheng Feng Compania<!--:-->
```

Widgets:

```
[:en]My name is Alex Chen.

I provide Spanish-English-Chinese

translation services in Taiwan.

<a href="mailto:alex@alexchen.info"><strong>I'm available for hire</strong></a>.

[:zh]我的名字是亞歷陳。

我提供西班牙語 - 英語 - 中國

在台灣的翻譯服務。

<a href="mailto:alex@alexchen.info"><strong>我可供租用</strong></a>.
```

None of these methods work for custom metaboxes.

Has anyone successfully integrated qtranslate with custom metaboxes?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Meta', true );
$lan = qtrans_getLanguage();
$meta_lan = qtrans_use( $lan, $meta, true );
echo $meta_lan;

?>
```

then enter your custom field data using the qtranslate comments:

```
<!--:ca-->CA<!--:--><!--:es-->ES<!--:--><!--:en-->EN<!--:-->
```

Answer (score 2):

In the output of your metabox in the page you want this to appear in you should wrap it in `__()`.

Maybe something like this:

```
echo __( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'your_field' ) );
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. I'm using the Genesis framework, so I used `echo __(genesis_get_custom_field('my_custom_field'));`

Comment: note: `echo __()` is the same as [`_e()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e)